# How to make Facebook Embedded comments box scroll-able in a div?

Tags: html, css

Ok so I have the embedded Comments box from the facebook developer page

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator
```

Everything loads up fine, except I have it in a Div separate from the code the page give you to embed with which has a background color and set to scroll so all the comments would be scrollable as it fills, yet when I add the embed code it removes my divs properties entirely

**HTML**

```css
#reviews {
    height:500px;
    width:950px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background:#7f7f7f;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="reviews">
     <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://chenacannabis.net" data- width="640" data-colorscheme="dark" data-numposts="5" >
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: avoid to use `center` tag:The `<center>` tag is not supported in HTML5..:https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

Comment: updated the code with CSS for centering, issue still remains the same

Comment: sorry i had to tell you it was an comment BTW (not an answer to your question)

Comment: _“yet when I add the embed code it removes my divs properties entirely”_ - the SDK doesn’t manipulate elements outside of the `fb-*` element that is used to embed the plugin. Problem not reproducible, please show a proper [mcve].